# Prove function is continuous using only topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Let(X,τ) be the subspace of R given by X= [0,1]∪[2,4].
Define Define f: (X,τ)→R by f(x) =1,if x∈[0,1] and 2,ifx∈[2,4]

So I am not allowed to use the epsilon delta definition. I can show that all preimage of open sets are open or preimage of all closed sets are closed which seems easier. So for any closed set in R not containing 1 or 2, the preimage is the empty set which is closed. If any closed set contains 1 or 2, then the preimage are the closed intervals given above which are closed. Same if we take the preimage of the entire real line which is also closed, thus the mapping is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is correct: for (closed) subsets $A$ of $\Bbb R$ there are $4$ options:

- $1 \in A$, $2 \notin A$, then $f^{-1}[A] = [0,1]$.
- $2 \in A$, $1 \notin A$, then $f^{-1}[A] = [2,4]$.
- $1 \in A$, $2 \in A$, then $f^{-1}[A] = X$.
- $1 \notin A$, $2 \notin A$, then $f^{-1}[A] = \emptyset$.

All of those optiosn give open and closed pre-images ($[0,1]$ is open in $X$ as it $X\setminus [0,1] = [2,4]$ is closed, e.g. or because it equals $(-1,3) \cap Y$ etc.)

So in this case going via open or closed pre-images comes down to the same thing.